# How to use determine the total length of 84 equal spaced suspenders

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

[image]

This has the function of $1280(\frac{e^{\frac{x}{1326} }+ e^{-\frac{x}{1326}}}{2}-1). -640\leq x\leq 640$

Across this bridge, it has 84 pairs of equally spaced vertical suspenders.

I have attempted to use the Riemann sum such as $\sum_{i=1}^{42}(\cosh(\frac{\frac{320i}{21}}{1326})-1 )(\frac{320}{21})$ giving $33346.25$

and also $\sum_{i=1}^{84}(\cosh(\frac{\frac{320i}{21}}{1326})-1 )(\frac{320}{21})$ giving $271499.70$

Is this the correct way of doing this or has something wrong been done?

Comment: 84 pairs would be 168 total suspenders. You're also converting the height to cosh, which is fine, but a little confusing since you don't do that in your original function. Also, why 320/21?

Comment: I just converted to $cosh$ for ease of use and $\frac{320}{21}$ comes from $\Delta x $ in the Riemann sum

Comment: If you're looking for total vertical length, I don't think you need dx? That would be more for area

Comment: The second Riemann sum should use 160 instead of 320. The original 320/21 has come from 640/42 right? It should be 640/84 in the finer division of the interval.
But as Barry Carter noted, you'll get the area under the cable this way, which seems to be a weird goal of computation. Could you please make your question clearer?